# try to access android.os.Build.SERIAL if available

Tags: android

Below is some code that I use to access `Build.SERIAL` static field, but it crashes when runs on Android 1.6!

```
// introduced in Android 2.3(API Level 9)
if (Integer.parseInt(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
            deviceID = android.os.Build.SERIAL; //cannot execute here if runs on Android 1.6!!!
}
```

That's the crash logs:

```
 DexOpt: couldn't find static field
 W/dalvikvm( 1098): VFY: unable to resolve static field 37 (SERIAL) in Landroid/os/Build;
 W/dalvikvm( 1098): VFY: rejecting opcode 0x62 at 0x0001
 W/dalvikvm( 1098): VFY: rejected Lcom/opera/mini/android/DisplayNotificationService;.getDeviceSerialID ()Ljava/lang/String;
 W/dalvikvm( 1098): Verifier rejected class Lcom/opera/mini/android/DisplayNotificationService;
 W/dalvikvm( 1098): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/opera/mini/android/DisplayNotificationService;)
 D/AndroidRuntime( 1098): Shutting down VM
 W/dalvikvm( 1098): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001da10)
 E/AndroidRuntime( 1098): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception`
```

So how to resolve this problem?

Comment: this code will not be reachable in 1.6 (you are comparing the build to Gingerbread)

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah, yeah, true, i knew this, but it just crash when runs on Android 1.6, no ideas about why!

Answer (score 0):

If you check the Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#GINGERBREAD) , `android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD` is supported since API level 9 (Gingerbread). Remove it from the If condition and do the check another way. For e.g. check that if SDK is greater than DONUT, then do something else get the serial.

**Update:**
 I mean try like this for e.g.:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 9) {
             deviceID = android.os.Build.SERIAL;
}
```

Comment: this is what I asked in the comments above, this line is not reachable for 1.6 !!

Comment: But why it crash? it should behavior as no those lines of code, shouldn't it?

Comment: The important thing is not to include `android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD` in your check. For e.g., you can use its integer value (9) like in my updated answer, or even better modify the `If` block to check for `DONUT` instead

Comment: sorry, actually use what you suggested, you can try yourself to see if it works!

Comment: What is the target SDK in your Manifest file

Comment: I already use similar code in my Apps, If your target SDK in Manifest file is 1.6, it will not compile

Comment: you're right, finally i use "@DontOptimize", that solve my problem, anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: I believe that SERIAL is only *required* to be present if the device has no telephony (e.g., a Wifi-only tablet).  So testing for the OS version may not be sufficient.  Reflection would seem to be a more foolproof way of determining whether this value (SERIAL) is available on a particular device.

Answer (score 0):

Use SDK_INT not SDK, as it's an integer not a string and removes the comparison issues you are suffering from.

This works for me:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9){
        deviceID = android.os.Build.SERIAL;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` instead of `Integer.parseInt(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK)` then check it by numbers like `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>9`